Tosibox hub upload to Proxmox VE
I have spent the past work week trying to figure out how to upload a qcow2 image of the tosibox hub into the ProxMox VE. I have tried converting it to an .iso and uploading it through the Prox. web interface, I have tried to upload just the .qcow2 image as well, and I receive the following error.
"Could not read from CDROM: error (0004)."
I was wondering if anyone has had any success in uploading tosibox as a bootable image into a VM in the Proxmox VE. I can hardly find any literature online about it. I've also ensured everything is uploaded correctly (checksums match, data integrity remains). I have tried mounting it via USB, through my laptop directly into the GUI, but to no avail. I am almost positive the .qcow2 image is the most compatible on the list of downloadable images on the tosibox site. is it worth trying another image possibly?
Thanks

While utilizing the Proxmox Virtual Environment, we encountered quite some difficulty in uploading the .qcow2 image to the VM. As a result, here is the step-by-step process in what we did to alleviate this issue. As opposed to an .iso file, the .qcow2 could not be simply uploaded to Proxmox. The steps following show how we resolved this issue.
Resolution (bash code highlighted)

Create VM with no OS (Do not use any media) in Proxmox GUI

ssh into Proxmox VE (root@serverip), or access the console on Proxmox GUI

Then we run a ‘qm disk import’ command in the terminal. This will directly create and add a disk with our qcow2 image on it.
qm disk import <vmid> <disk-image-path> <storage-id> --format <disk-format>


Wait for upload, then our disk with the image should appear in the web interface. Detach the original hard disk that was automatically assigned to the VM on creation
a.  You can do this in the Proxmox GUI by highlighting the disk then clicking ‘detach’ in the drop-down menu

Change the default seaBIOS to UEFI. This will change the boot format to match what TosiBox uses.

Change the boot order, prioritizing this new disk as the first booted.

Startup the VM and the TosiBox license input page should appear (For TosiBox Hub)


